# Bundle install not working (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm new to rails and I'm trying to run 'bundle install', only that I keep getting the following message:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in     `fetch_all_remote_specs': undefined method `list' for #<Gem::SpecFetcher:0x000006002f13a8> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `block in index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:168:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:102:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I've reinstalled rails and bundler without any success.
I can't work on a new app without bundle install please help?

Comment: try to update your bundler to 1.6 and/or ruby to >2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to update `Bundler` try:

```
gem update bundler
```

Check ([github issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2411))

#### Update:

You can either `gem uninstall bundler` (select older version) to get rid of older one or specifiy exact version for your rails app, in `Gemfile`

```
gem 'bundler', '~> 1.6.2' #VERSION OF NEWER BUNDLER
```

Comment: I get Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

Comment: try suggested solutions in updated answer and let me know how it goes!